# Foreach MySql Table

Tags: c#, mysql

I have connected to my MySQL Database and have received output from directly typing a command in my code, but I want to add a feature where it asks what command you want to query specifically during runtime. Then I want it to do a for each to go through and retrieve all data referred to in the runtime query. This is my code ATM and I get errors.

```
try
        {
            con.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection Open!");

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Query:");
            comString = Console.ReadLine();

            try
            {
                MySqlDataReader myReader = null;
                MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(comString, con);
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(myReader["ID"].ToString() + " | " + myReader["NAME"].ToString() + " | " + myReader["PERMISSIONS"].ToString());
                    foreach (string i in myReader)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(myReader["i"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

EDIT

This is the error i receive below

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' to type 'System.String'.
```

at sqlConnection.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Pathssss\sqlConnection\sqlConnection\Program.cs:line 50

Comment: Please share these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in `foreach` statement you are trying to cast `object` to `string`. Use this code to replace your `while` block.

```
int count = myReader.FieldCount;
while(myReader .Read()) 
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetValue(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: you my friend are a pure genius!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to use libraries I would suggest using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net), will make your life a lot easier.

with dapper all you would have to do is this:

```
bool firstRun = true;
foreach(var result in con.Query(comString))
{
   var rDictionary = (IDictionary<string,object>)result;

   //assuming this is what you want based off of your commented out code
   if(firstRun){
       firstRun = false;
       Console.Write(string.Join("|",rDictionary.Keys));
   }

   Console.WriteLine( 
           string.Join("|", rDictionary.Select(a=>a.Value ?? (object)"NULL").ToArray())
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you another (I think better) way to do this:

```
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Connection Open!");

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Query:");
        comString = Console.ReadLine();
        MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(comString, con);
        MySqlDataAdapter msda = new MySqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        msda.Fill(ds);
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            Console.WriteLine(dr["column"].ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
```